# Can I use OSB or plywood instead of 1x6 boards to hang metal panels?

Tags: studs, plywood, hanging

I'm going to be putting up two louvered panels that will hold plastic hanging bins (think akro-bin type). I won't be able to mount the panels on studs, so I'm trying to decide if I should mount regular boards or OSB behind the panels. The panels weigh 11lbs each, and I'll probably have no more than a 100-150lbs of stuff in all the bins.

If I go with OSB, I would put up something larger than the panels do it would easy to mount  other things from this area later. But, I'm concerned OSB isn't strong enough to support the weight. Is it?

***UPDATE*** (I moved my "answer" to here and expanded it for other to find): I ended up using two 5ft x 2ft x 5/8in panels made of pine rather than OSB. They are screwed into three wall studs. I ended up with way less than 100lbs hanging on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OSB or plywood would be a suitable substructure. It will distribute the load and create a stable mounting surface for your assembly. OSB is similarly strong to plywood and can be  more uniform, depending on the grade of plywood. Its drawback is its susceptibility to swelling and flaking due to repeated moisture exposure.

Individual boards are less solid as a system and you may end up with concentrated loads. That said, if they're mounted solidly, they could carry substantial weight as well.

The key is that the anchors you use in the substructure need to be adequate to grab sufficiently in only 1/2" of material. Larger diameter screws substantially increase pullout strength.

Answer (score 0):

Use Marine grade ply, water won't affect it, it's a neat finish and will do the job. Only problem it is more expensive though that might not be the case after you finish tarting up the alternative materials.

Comment: Why does it matter whether water will affect the support? The original poster didn't mention any sort of wet environment.